# Heroku Rails asset pipeline fails to precompile after adding font

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I'm trying to add a font to my Rails app this is what I've done:

Added fonts to:

```
-app
--assets
---fonts
```

SCSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: LigatureSymbols;

  src: font-url('LigatureSymbols211.eot');
  src: local('LigatureSymbols'),
       font-url('LigatureSymbols211.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       font-url('LigatureSymbols211.woff') format('woff'),
       font-url('LigatureSymbols211.ttf') format('truetype'),
       font-url('LigatureSymbols211.svg#LigatureSymbols') format('svg');

  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

`production.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

But when I push to my Heroku production server I get this:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.804043 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/LigatureSymbols211-c5b7db18fa0fcd910e92fee751776047.eot
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.809822 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/LigatureSymbols211-09ff8be41a6bee98c834e9a278bb8b28.otf
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.812685 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/LigatureSymbols211-1f682b1be252dbf6182d606a185b603f.svg
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.819262 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/LigatureSymbols211-9e88765b872185b22e519da056cba9f0.ttf
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.829518 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/LigatureSymbols211-a2d90ca6deff46bfcf9cade63d4902ce.woff
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:07.838351 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/rails-5f9b3f343d9831cbf50b9bc980faf39b.png
       I, [2013-05-06T06:21:17.072501 #2036]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/public/assets/application-6af5b81b9fcc820f1d43b4135f00317e.js
       rake aborted!
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
       (in /tmp/build_2snusxy9gm4d7/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

I tried to add a `required` line in my `application.css` but that wouldn't work either.

**EDIT:**

I can access `localhost:5000/assets/LigatureSymbols-2.11.eot` on my dev machine when running the server.  Not sure if this might help narrow what's going wrong

**EDIT 2:**

The code works with the SCSS font commented out, is there a syntax error?

**EDIT 3:**

This is at the top of the trace stack:

```
.../sprockets-2.9.2/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:63:in `sprockets_context'
.../sprockets-2.9.2/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:42:in `font_url'
```

is there something wrong with my `font-url` calls?

**EDIT 4:**

Removed dashes from font filenames and changed scss to reflect, but same error persists

**EDIT 5:**

Generated CSS on local machine:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: LigatureSymbols;
  src: font-url("LigatureSymbols211.eot");
  src: local("LigatureSymbols"), font-url("LigatureSymbols211.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), font-url("LigatureSymbols211.woff") format("woff"), font-url("LigatureSymbols211.ttf") format("truetype"), font-url("LigatureSymbols211.svg#LigatureSymbols") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it out!  Strangest thing... might be a bug in SASS.

If I put the code directly in the file `home.css.scss` which was required in my `application.css`, the error would occur.

Additionally, if I placed the font SCSS in a seperate file (`font.scss`) and `@import "font"` it would also raise an error.

*Only* if I required the `font.scss` file in my `application.css` would the asset pipeline pass.

It didn't matter if I used `font-url(...)` vs `asset-url(...,font)` vs `url(asset-path(...,font))`  They all work when the font was included via a `=require` in the `application.css`

Comment: I added a not-very-well-received answer to the related issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36539357/1965639

By changing the font.scss to font.css and including it differently, I solved the issue. @Michael Johnston pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the hyphens. The assets pipeline uses hyphens for fingerprinting the assets and having hyphens in your font paths is causing issues.

Comment: Renamed the files to `LigatureSymbols211` dot whatever and am still getting the same error.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Can you access the fonts at the expected url? i.e. something.com/fonts/LigatureSymbols211.eot or something.com/LigatureSymbols211.eot

Comment: On my local machine / dev server yes, I can access at `/assets/LigatureSymbols211.eot` and the other extensions.  I tried on production server with a fingerprint before the pre compilation aborts, but it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, I just commented the SCSS out, the asset pipeline passes, and **was** able to navigate to the font on my production server at `/assets/LigatureSymbols211-c5b7db18fa0fcd910e92fee751776047.eot`  The problem seems to lie in my `font-url` for some reason

Comment: I'd copy the production generated css and do a search for LigatureSymbols and see what it is generating as the url. At this point, I think font-url is the culprit as well.

Comment: I added what is generated in my CSS file to the main post. This is on my local server though, if I have the `font-url` statements in my SCSS, the production server won't update to show the css

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error when I forgot to change the file extension from .css to .scss. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I have had similar issues with Heroku and this helped sometimes.
It's worth a try. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: This was already in my `config/application.rb` thanks for the suggestion though