# Require statement in application.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, fancybox, colorbox

I want to use a lightbox gem such as fancybox or color box. Both gems ask to add this line in the application.css

```
 *= require colorbox-rails
```

Here's the problem. I only have application.css.scss files. All my css files are scss files. I have import statements in the application.css.scss but no *=require statements. Adding the above line results in the error :

Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "=require colorb..."

Here's the complete application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "welcome";
@import "sessions";
@import "users";


*= require colorbox-rails
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`application.css.scss` or `application.css` are kinda the same. Just rename your `application.css` to `application.css.scss`.

As for adding that line, it'll need to be right up the top, in a comment. Like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require colorbox-rails
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "welcome";
@import "sessions";
@import "users";
```

Comment: Shouldn't use *= require_anything in sass/scss file?

Comment: As @masaaki says, is this a bad practice to mix/match requires/import?

Comment: @masaaki why dont you give an alternate answer then. I am a noob but I dont know what to do now because of your comments.

Comment: @orange14 above solution will work just fine. Don't be put off. Some might consider it tidier to pull all those `@imports` down the bottom into a separate file like `my_files.css.scss` and then add an extra line `*= require my_files`.

The `@import` lines are SCSS and the `*= require` lines are rails-specific stuff, not SCSS. So, maybe it's kinda tidier to keep them separate, but it doesn't matter too much either way. I don't bother separating them.

Comment: Thanks @joshua.paling, I have no application.css file in my project but an application.scss. In every tutorial online they tell me to add a *= require my_files. So I am adding everything in anpplication.scss. Dont know if this is the way to go since I am a noob but thanks for your prompt response.Your response helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly, I had this issue with fonts files declaring different font-faces using a single font.scss file in my stylesheets directory (Rails app using sass and haml). I had followed related issues (like [this article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391821/heroku-rails-asset-pipeline-fails-to-precompile-after-adding-font/16392942)) and had tried a number of related solutions like removing '-' from font ttf filename, changing the url declarations in the font.scss file, etc.

@joshua.paling's solution worked for me ...

1. Change the font.scss file name to font.css
2. utilize the following declaration style in the application.scss file:

   ```
   /* ...    
   *= require_self    
   *= require fonts    
   */
   # @import other files here excluding the font.css file
   ```

And with this configuration the following font-face declarations still worked

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: PT Serif;
   src: url('PT_SerifWebRegular.ttf') format("truetype");
 }
```

Comment: If the other answer worked for you, the appropriate behavior is to upvote their answer, not post a new answer indicating that it worked.

Comment: Which I did, but this is related and worth posting. Bad form to down vote an attempt to tie a similar error to multiple causes and save someone the three hours I took to solve my problem. Explicitly, I did not get to this answer by looking for font-face related problems, or by looking for SASS / CSS issues. SO is not just about answers, but about solutions.

Comment: No, it's about solving the problem that was asked.  No one asked about font-face, so it looks like you're posting a mix of "thanks joshua.paling!" with answering another question entirely.  Just because you solved a problem with the aid of another answer doesn't mean you should go posting random answers where they don't belong.